# How to set cursor after the text in a textbox on TextChange Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, cursor, textchanged

I have a textbox **txtZipCode**. On the **TextChange** event, i am populating data in other two textboxes **txtState** and **txtCity**. What i want to do is, i want to set the cursor after the **Text** of **txtState**.

I am doing `txtState.Focus()`
but, the cursor is displaying on the left side of the text...i want to set the cursor after the text.

Any Suggestions ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,
`txtState.Attributes["onfocus"] = "javascript:this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length,this.value.length);";`

Comment: There is no such property as **Select** of a textbox in web-forms

Answer (score 1):

This should help after focus:

```
txtState.SelectionStart = txtState.Text.Length -1;
txtState.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Comment: It is not Winforms....it is asp.net webforms

There is no such property like SelectionStart